# Cursor for loop.. Reason for not using open,fetch,close

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi I am having 2 set of codes here

1.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR C_EMP IS SELECT * FROM EMP;
    TEMP EMP%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

OPEN C_EMP;
    FOR TEMP IN C_EMP 
    LOOP
        FETCH C_EMP INTO TEMP;
        UPDATE EMP SET NAME = 'Great' where id = 1;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMP ID IS '|| TEMP.ID);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMP NAME IS '||TEMP.NAME);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMP SALARY IS '||TEMP.SALARY);
    END LOOP;
CLOSE C_EMP;    
END;
```

2.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR C_EMP IS SELECT * FROM EMP;
    --TEMP EMP%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

--OPEN C_EMP;
    FOR TEMP IN C_EMP 
    LOOP
        --FETCH C_EMP INTO TEMP;
        UPDATE EMP SET NAME = 'Great' where id = 1;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMP ID IS '|| TEMP.ID);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMP NAME IS '||TEMP.NAME);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMP SALARY IS '||TEMP.SALARY);
    END LOOP;
--CLOSE C_EMP;  
END;
```

In the second one if I remove the open,fetch,close code is working fine. But the first code is throwing an error cursor already open.
 What is the reason for this?

Comment: Could you please post the complete exception stack, with line numbers, error codes and description that you are getting?

Comment: The reason is that you can not (and must not) use explicit OPEN/FETCH/CLOSE with cursor FOR statement. Please study Oracle documentation  - you will find that cusror FOR loop makes OPEN/FETCH/CLOSE operations implicitly and you even don't need declare the variable to fetch cursor in - Oracle makes this itself. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense - why do you need a FOR loop in the first place, when you always update the record with ID = 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

FOR LOOP uses implicit cursors, so you don't need to open, close and fetch from cursor:

```
FOR temp IN (SELECT * FROM emp) LOOP
   -- refer to temp inside this loop
END LOOP;
```

is all what you need to do...